# Removing Search Box from the Start Menu without disabling indexing

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Server 2008 R2 Terminal Services Box (Though solutions for Windows 7 should work fine) which used Desktop Experience to give a Windows 7 style to the end user:

[image: Start Menu]

I've been asked to remove the "Search Box", but the only methods I've found remove it from Explorer or involve disabling indexing altogether.

I'd like to avoid these, so is it possible to remove it from JUST the start menu?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off all of the items that get searched, but that doesn't make the search box *disappear*:

[image: screenshot of customize]

For that, you need to use [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/). Look! No search!

[image: classic shell]

Comment: The customer won't be happy with the latter!

Comment: Customer happiness was not a stated requirement! :D (you can edit that menu all you want so it looks like the top one)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately deploying an "unknown" 3rd Party App just isn't going to be an option at all sadly.